# Is there an expression to describe a poor woman who marries a rich man for money?

Tags: expressions

Wikipedia reads that in Spanish *[Dar el braguetazo](http://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braga_%28prenda_de_vestir%29)* 'se dice de un hombre que ha encontrado un buen partido para casarse, que le saca de toda penuria y preocupación,'  — e.g., to marry for money, where the man is poor and the woman is rich.

I don't know why, but after some searches I found no Spanish expression to describe, contrary to "Dar el braguetazo", a marriage of a poor woman to a rich man, which is, as far as I know, a more common case.

Thus, my question is, at least in English, is there an expression to describe a poor woman who marries for money a rich man?

Comment: Why assume it's a poor woman? Rich women are much more likely to be able to marry for money.

Comment: What do I call a *poor* woman who marries for money? Sensible.

Answer (score 18):

[*Gold digger*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_digger) is the usual term for somebody who pursues a relationship for money. Its connotation is more greed than poverty, however. If you want a more neutral term, I'd suggest [*marriage of convenience.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_of_convenience)

Comment: Perhaps the ultimate form of *social climbing*.

Answer (score 5):

Consider **[hypergamy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergamy)**

> (colloquially referred to as *"marrying up"*) is the act or practice of marrying a spouse of higher caste or status than oneself.

The term does not specifically refer to money, but social class or caste and money are very closely related.

Comment: This answer may not be as good as Bradd's, but it certainly makes a nice complement to Bradd's. I'm glad you gave it a mention.

Comment: @J.R. I agree that Brad's answer is the most appropriate for common parlance (and I voted it up even before I looked this one up), but in the realm of esoteric pomposity ...